# Typescript shorthand for interfaces or types with properties of same type

Tags: typescript

Is there a sugar syntax in TypeScript where I can say type of all interface(/types) properties is same & not mention it against each property.

Eg:

```
export interface allStrings {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

// Sugard as something like this(Pseudo)
export interface allStrings<string> {
    prop1,popp2;
}
```

Edit: I'm not looking for an interface to say object with all values of type string but more of an object with only specified keys & each has a value of type string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is similar to `Record<'prop1' | 'prop2', string>`

Comment: only challenge with this is I cannot use Record syntax inside of an interface defn, but only type defn.
Eg: type A {a: Record<'x'|'y', string>} is fine but interface A {a: Record<'x'|'y', string>} complains

Answer (score 4):

```
export interface AllSameType<T> {
    [k: string]: T;
}
```

This is an interface of an object with properties of any name and all will be the same type, T.

Usage:

`const strs: AllSameType<string> = { a: '', b: 1 }; // Error, b is not string`

Comment: I want to still restrict what the keys are gonna be. Like in my example I want objects to only prop1 & prop2.

Comment: Well then the only "short" version is this: `export interface AllSameType<T> {
    prop1: T; prop2: T;
}` And use like: `const strs: AllSameType<string>`, but it's not much shorter. You will still have to type the generic `T` on every property. What you're looking for *exactly* is not possible.

Comment: This is generic typing. I'm looking for just a sugar syntax.

Comment: What you're looking for exactly is not possible.